# Unable to Upload to App Store from Xcode 7.2

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I am attempting to upload an app to the `app store`, but the upload button is greyed out. It says distribution requires enrollment in the Apple developer program. I am indeed enrolled and have set up everything for the application on `iTunes Connect` other than the build. I have tried quitting `Xcode`, signing out and back in, etc, but nothing seems to work. Any ideas? Please keep in mind that I am relatively new to iOS development so I am not very familiar with the highly technical side of things like code `signing` and `certificates`.

Here's an image of what I'm talking about for clarity:

[image: Xcode Archive Organizer]

Comment: Did you use the correct signing when archiving?

Comment: I believe so, I set my provisioning profile and signed for distribution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to register your account: [Apple Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enroll/). It costs $ 99 a year.

You also need to generate a iOS Certificate for Production (App Store and Ad Hoc) in [Apple Member Center](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/certificateCreate.action)

[image: Certificate in Apple Member Center]

A tip is use `Application Loader` instead of `Xcode`.

To download the `Application Loader`

- Go to `Itunes Connect > My Apps > App > Prepare for Submission > Build`

This Application handle better the submission of your App.

[image: Application Loader]

Comment: I have paid already am registered; that shouldn't be the issue. I tried application loader but it requires a .ipa file correct? I cannot generate one as the export button is greyed out.

Comment: Have you generated a iOS Certificate for Production (App Store and Ad Hoc) in https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/certificateCreate.action ?

Comment: Essentially, the issue I was having was linked to my provisioning profile so I ended up scrapping my certificates and app id and starting off fresh, which worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. I resolved it by switching my Code Signing away from iOS Developer (to iOS Distribution or iPhone Developer), attempting to archive (Build > Archive) then back to iOS Developer (then archive again). Not sure why, but the button was enabled after this.

See Ray Wenderlich's [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/133121/testflight-tutorial-ios-beta-testing) on testflight.

[image]